# How to filter an array of objects storing only once for each matched item

Tags: javascript

I'm working with Javascript, and have the following array of objects:

```
const offersStep = [
     {a: 1, price: 67.10},
     {a: 3, price: 88.20},
     {a: 5, price: 88.20}, 
     {a: 7, price: 57.10},
     {a: 13, price: 57.10},
     {a: 15, price: 57.10},
     {a: 29, price: 57.10},
     {a: 30, price: 57.10},
]
```

What and How i have to do, in order to **store in a new array**, those objects, ignoring it those who the prop `price` has a value who is already stored on the new array?

Expected output:

```
offers = [
  {a: 1, price: 67.10},
  {a: 3, price: 88.20},
  {a: 7, price: 57.10}
]
```

Comment: So, remove items with duplicate prices (except the first instance).

Comment: but how can i do that?

Comment: Before adding to `offers`, check whether there's already an offer with the same price. You can use `.find()` or `.some()` to check this.

Comment: I posted an answer. You can check and let me know if it worked for you or not! Thanks! @EduardoRanieroSilva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use iteration to determine if previously saved prices match the current object being iterated.

```
const offersStep = [
     {a: 1, price: 67.10},
     {a: 3, price: 88.20},
     {a: 5, price: 88.20}, 
     {a: 7, price: 57.10},
     {a: 13, price: 57.10},
     {a: 15, price: 57.10},
     {a: 29, price: 57.10},
     {a: 30, price: 57.10},
]

// Vars to store previously recorded prices.
var storedPrices = [];

// Var to store unique offersStep.
var uniqueOffersStep = [];

// Iterates through each of the offersStep array objects.
offersStep.forEach (function(value) {
  // Sets a boolean to false .. used later to determine if the current object is added to the unique array.
  var isSkip = false;
  
  // Iterates through each of the storedPrices array.
  storedPrices.forEach (function(spvalue) {
    // If the current objects price matches one of the storedPrices then it sets the skip flag to true.
    if (value.price == spvalue) {
      isSkip = true;
    }
  })
  // Adds the current objects price to the storedPrices array.
  storedPrices.push(value.price);
  
  // Check if the skip flag is still false after checking stored prices and adds the object to the uniqueOffers variable.
  if (isSkip == false) {
    uniqueOffersStep.push(value);
  }
})

// Outputs the final var to console.
console.log(uniqueOffersStep);
```

**As this relies on multiple layers of iteration it would be fairly resource heavy with larger data sets.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm working with salesforce, which uses an older version of JS, so your answer worked. Really saved me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store the objects in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) keyed off its `price`. After you have stored unique prices, spread the [values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) iterator of the Map into a new array to get your result.

```js
const offersStep = [
     {a: 1, price: 67.10},
     {a: 3, price: 88.20},
     {a: 5, price: 88.20}, 
     {a: 7, price: 57.10},
     {a: 13, price: 57.10},
     {a: 15, price: 57.10},
     {a: 29, price: 57.10},
     {a: 30, price: 57.10},
];

function filterOffers(offers) {
  let offersByPrice = new Map();
  for (let offer of offers) {
    if (!offersByPrice.has(offer.price)) {
      // Store the offer
      offersByPrice.set(offer.price, offer);
    }
  }
  
  return [...offersByPrice.values()];
}

console.log(filterOffers(offersStep));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**

Filter the original array, keeping tabs on the prices encountered so far by means of a set.

**Code**

```js
const offersStep = [
     {a: 1, price: 67.10},
     {a: 3, price: 88.20},
     {a: 5, price: 88.20}, 
     {a: 7, price: 57.10},
     {a: 13, price: 57.10},
     {a: 15, price: 57.10},
     {a: 29, price: 57.10},
     {a: 30, price: 57.10}
];

let offer
  , nset_prices = new Set() 
  ;

offer = offersStep.filter ( po_item => {
            let b_ok = !nset_prices.has(po_item.price)
              ;

            if (b_ok) {
                nset_prices.add(po_item.price)
            }
            return b_ok;
        });

console.log(offer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me if the code works for you!

```js
const offersStep = [
  { a: 1, price: 67.1 },
  { a: 3, price: 88.2 },
  { a: 5, price: 88.2 },
  { a: 7, price: 57.1 },
  { a: 13, price: 57.1 },
  { a: 15, price: 57.1 },
  { a: 29, price: 57.1 },
  { a: 30, price: 57.1 },
];

let tempOffers = {};

offersStep.forEach((eachObj) => {
  const { price } = eachObj;
  if (!tempOffers[price]) {
    tempOffers[price] = eachObj;
  }
});

const offers = Object.values(tempOffers);

console.log("offers are", offers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArray = offersStep.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    if(acc.find(item => item.a === curr.a)) {
        return acc
    }
    return acc.concat(curr)
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter with a set of prices.

```js
const
    filterWithSet = s => ({ price }) => !s.has(price) && s.add(price),
    offersStep = [{ a: 1, price: 67.10 }, { a: 3, price: 88.20 }, { a: 5, price: 88.20 },  { a: 7, price: 57.10 }, { a: 13, price: 57.10 }, { a: 15, price: 57.10 }, { a: 29, price: 57.10 }, { a: 30, price: 57.10 }],
    result = offersStep.filter(filterWithSet(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), and [`ternary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator, to iterate given array, check if item price is existing, and append to a collection array if not found:

```js
const offersStep = [
     {a: 1, price: 67.10},
     {a: 3, price: 88.20},
     {a: 5, price: 88.20}, 
     {a: 7, price: 57.10},
     {a: 13, price: 57.10},
     {a: 15, price: 57.10},
     {a: 29, price: 57.10},
     {a: 30, price: 57.10},
]

const offers = offersStep.reduce(
  (arr, item) => // collection array, and iteration item
     // check collection array for item price
     (arr.find(item2 => item2.price === item.price))
         ? arr // item price exists so return array unchanged
         : [...arr, item], // return array with item appended
  [] // initial collection array
);
console.log(offers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
// data source
const offersStep = [
     {a: 1, price: 67.10},
     {a: 3, price: 88.20},
     {a: 5, price: 88.20}, 
     {a: 7, price: 57.10},
     {a: 13, price: 57.10},
     {a: 15, price: 57.10},
     {a: 29, price: 57.10},
     {a: 30, price: 57.10},
];

// this is the array to store new objects after dupliacte check
const offers =[]; 

offersStep.forEach(
     (d,i)=>{
     //push the first object from the array of objects
         (i==0)?offers.push({a:d.a,price:d.price}):
    //for the subsequent index, check offers if there exists at least one  
    // value for price that matches the current price from offersStep.price
    // if yes, don't push, else push
             offers.some(x=>x.price==d.price)===false?offers.push({a:d.a,price:d.price}):null 
     }
     );
console.log(offers);
```